# Is it possible for a program to force windows 10 to page it out

Tags: windows, memory-management

I would like to force windows 10 to page out my program (or another program) and then at a later stage (probably via a second program) have windows page my program back in

Comment: Look at the `EmptyWorkingSet` function

Comment: That is very helpful indeed. I assume i simply reference the paged data to reload it from memory or is there a function to achieve that? What i would like to do is;
1) EmptyWorkingSet()
2) Block on a pipe or sleep
3) Another process wakes this process or the pipe is unblocked
My process continues